# Is it possible to open mat-dialog in a new tab in Angular?

Tags: angular, dialog

I am just wondering that it is available to open dialog in a new tab in Angular.

The original one opens dialog in the same page but I want to open the dialog in a new tab or window.

Is it possible? If so, how can I approach that?

Answer (score 0):

my app-routing.module

```
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SettingsComponent } from './components/settings/settings.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
component: HomeComponent
 },
  {
path: 'settings',
component: SettingsComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
  })


export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

my app.modle

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   HomeComponent,
   WebviewDirective,
   SettingsComponent
  ],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
AppRoutingModule,
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
})
  ],
 providers: [ElectronService],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
 export class AppModule {
}
```

my home.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
 })
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

const remote = require('electron').remote;
const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;

// Create a browser window
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  center: true,
  resizable: false,
  frame: true,
  transparent: false
});

// Load the page + route
win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html#/settings');
  }

}
```

Comment: What is 'electron'?

Comment: Oh! I figured it out what it is. By the way is there any way to using nothing? I mean I would like to use only Angular stuff.